# unable to install yii user module

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I downloaded the latest release of Yii user module from github and extracted it under

```
protected/modules/
```

directory so my directory structure under this include the user and other modules included in the zip. I made changes to the main file as mentioned in the docs so my main.php now looks like this

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.modules.user.models.*',
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',

),

  'modules'=>array(
    // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'sheikh24',
        // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
    ),
            'user' => array(
                    'debug' => true,
            )

),
'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            'class' => 'application.modules.user.components.YumWebUser',
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
            'loginUrl' => array('//user/user/login'),

        ),
    // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

        'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ewindow',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
                    'tablePrefix' => '',
    ),
    'errorHandler'=>array(
        // use 'site/error' action to display errors
        'errorAction'=>'index/error',
    ),
    'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
            /*
            array(
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            ),
            */
        ),
    ),
)
```

so as you can see I have all the code setup but when I hit the url

```
http://localhost/ewindow/index.php?r=user/install
```

I got the following error

```
include(UserModule.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

or I try to hit some other page in my application I get the error

```
include(YumWebUser.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here ? please help me .

**EDIT :**

here is the link to the extentsion 
https://github.com/thyseus/yii-user-management

Comment: when asking questions about extensions, please include a link to the extensions page, there are many extensions for user management, how would i know which one are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/thyseus/yii-user-management

Comment: @bool.dev can you please help me.. I am unable to figure out the error

Comment: Can you post the error? It will help a lot.

Comment: @Faizan actually i haven't used this extension before, so i don't know. i'll try and use it and see if i get the error. will let you know, don't worry!

Comment: @Skatox I have posted the error.. Its the same error I get.. do u want me to post the whole stack trace ?

Comment: i too experiencing this error

Comment: just turn on the php shot tags !! it will solve the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My way of figure out this issue is to turn on short_open_tag in php.ini file. It was Off before I modified it.

Answer (score 3):

Check wamp server settings also. specially the php version you are using...

Comment: what are your settings on wamp server ? is it working at your end

Comment: I am using wapserver 2.2 and php version 5.3.8 and apache version 2.2.21. Also try re-installing your wamp server may be it does the trick.

Comment: thanks !! it worked fine after configuring he wamp server again

Comment: What settings did you change on the server to get this to work? - You say it worked - but what did you change?

Comment: just turned on the php short tags !!

Answer (score 1):

check files permisions also:

```
chmod -R go+rx protected/modules
```

Comment: where to check these file permission. I am running on WAMP + Windows 7 . I dont had any issues with file permissions before

Answer (score 1):

It seems the module developer used short_open_tags in. i.e, `<? ?>` instead of `<?php ?>`. So just enable it in PHP.

In Xampp, locate php.ini and set `short_open_tags = On`

Answer (score 0):

```
'modules'=>array(

'user' => array(
        'debug' => false,
        ),

 'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'sheikh24',
        // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
    ),
            'user' => array(
                    'debug' => true,
            )

),
```

apply this changes and try out.

Comment: does this mean I have to setup user table as well ?

Comment: because as far as I understand user table will be generated by script

Comment: that I am already doing.. if you see your updated code you will see that user module is loaded twice. one with debug="true" and one with debug="false". one before Gii module and one after GIi moduke

Answer (score 0):

on the model of user module, open file UserLogin.php

you can try edit function like this

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'rememberMe'=>Yii::t("User.user", "Remember me next time"),
        'username'=>Yii::t("User.user", "username or email"),
        'password'=>Yii::t("User.user", "password"),
    );
}
```